# Update ESP8266 esp-01 AT command Firmware?

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266

I am trying to install AT command official firmware and so far I am not able to find a reliable way to do that. I have tried using the official flasher tool from Espressif's website but I do not know what hex values should I put in that and what bin files and in which order should I put in that. I have tried so many tutorial and I think all of them are out of date in firmware version.(Also which firmware should I download from the website and my esp8266 module is 8 Mbit module.)

Comment: Check this video https://youtu.be/wXXXgaePZX8

Answer (score 1):

#### AT 1.7

AT firmware 1.7.x is build on Espressif NonOS SDK 3.

The Espressif AT binary is built for 2MB-c1 flash partitioning. Flash Download Tool corrects it for 4 MB flash, but for esptool you should use the `--flash_size 2MB-c1` option and the corresponding addresses.

```
esptool.py write_flash --flash_size 2MB-c1 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/1024+1024/user1.2048.new.5.bin 0x1fb000 blank.bin 0x1fc000 esp_init_data_default_v08.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x1fe000 blank.bin
```

The AT 1.7.4 version has bin file for flashing to 1 MB flash.

```
esptool.py write_flash --flash_size 1MB 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/512+512/user1.1024.new.2.bin 0xfb000 blank.bin 0xfc000 esp_init_data_default_v08.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x7e000 blank.bin
```

For some esp8266 modules you will have to add `--flash_mode dout` before `--flash_size`.

Resources:

- [the Espressif NonOS SDK with AT binaries](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/releases) - versions 1.7.x
- [AT 1.7 reference](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf) - it contains firmware flashing instructions too

#### AT 2.1

AT firmware 2.1.x is build on Espressif RTOS SDK for esp8266 and esp32.

The flashing command of AT2 with esptool is `esptool.py write_flash @download.config`. I recommend to change in download.config file flash_mode to qio if your ESP module supports it and flash frequency to 40MHz if your module doesn't support 80MHz.

Resources:

- [the Espressif AT2 binaries](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/AT_Binary_Lists/index.html)

#### Flashing tools

- [Flash Download Tool](https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14) It is Windows only, but can detect settings of your ESP and apply them to the flashed settings binary
- [esptool.py installation instructions](https://github.com/espressif/esptool#installation--dependencies)

Comment: Of the above, it looks like only the 1MB option of the 1.7.x firmware will work for flashing to a 1MB device like the ESP-01S and 1MB versions of the ESP-01.  I'm guessing 2.x is abandoning devices with <2MB flash.  An argument in favor of the ESP-12F module instead of the ESP-01 series - an upgrade albeit with different pinout and harder for hobbyists/prototyping.

Comment: @tomr., the 2.1 can be build for 1 MB. here is a build for esp-01 https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/wiki/files/ESP8266-1MB-tx1rx3-AT_V2.1.zip

Comment: https://github.com/CytronTechnologies/esp-at-binaries also provides binaries for ESP-01 for 2.2.0 firmware. I understood after a lot of head scratching that the UART pins were moved in official firmware, thus no response for `AT` on updating the firmware.